# Можно ли как-то ждать List<Task> пока один из Task в списке не вернет true?

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли как-то ждать `List<Task>` пока один из `Task` в списке не вернет `true`?

Comment: `await Task.WhenAny(your_list.ToArray())`?

Comment: Вроде бы это просто будет ждать первого завершенного Task. А мне нужно, чтобы он вернул Task только в том случае, если Task вернет true

Comment: а если ни один из тасков true не вернет?

Comment: А ну да, будет вечно ждать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, вот так

```
public async Task<bool> WhenOneTask(List<Task<bool>> list)
{
    while(list.Any())
    {
        var newList = new List<Task<bool>>();
        foreach(var t in list)
        {
            if (t.IsCompleted)
            {
                if (t.Result) return t.Result;
            }
            else newList.Add(t);
        }

        list = newList;
        await Task.WhenAny(list);
    }

    // тут все таски кончились, но результата нужного нет   
    return false;
}
```

Как проверить

```
var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>() {
    Task.Run(async ()=>{await Task.Delay(2000); return false;}),
    Task.Run(async ()=>{await Task.Delay(3000); return false;}),
    Task.Run(async ()=>{await Task.Delay(4000); return false;}),
    Task.Run(async ()=>{await Task.Delay(3500); return true;}),     
};

await WhenOneTask(tasks);
```